# redisplay django form after successfull call to is_valid() with custom error message

Tags: django, validation

I have a django form that first validates its data through calling form.is_valid(). If its not, the form is redisplayed, with an error message regarding the invalid data.
Now if is_valid() is true, I try to save the data in an ldap backend. If the form.cleaned_data is not in correspondance with the ldap data type, I get an Exception from my ldap save method. Now what I would like to do in this case is to redisplay the form with an error message, just like the thing that happens after form.is_valid() returns false.
I tried reading some docs and also some django source, but could not find where I could hook into this.

An alternative would be to carefully build the form of (custom) form fields that would "guarantee" that the data is allready compliant to ldap syntax. 
But I would like to make shure that I catch ldap syntax errors and display them in a convenient form. So if I could hook into that form redisplay mechanism would make me a happy little programmer :-)

Any ideas or hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under your class for the form that extends `forms.Form`, add one of the following methods, assuming you have a `is_valid_ldap_data()` defined somewhere:

for a whole form:

```
def clean(self):
    if !is_valid_ldap_data(self.cleaned_data.get("fieldname")):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid LDAP data type");
    return self.cleaned_data
```

or for a single field:

```
def clean_fieldname(self):
    if !is_valid_ldap_data(self.cleaned_data['fieldname'])):
        raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid LDAP data type");
    return self.cleaned_data['fieldname']
```

Answer (score 1):

At your Form subclass implement custom field validation method

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

Validation logic must go where it belongs. If `form.is_valid() == True` than `form.cleaned_data` must be valid. Just because code says so. You want to hide some of validation logic somewhere else -- and that is just bad practice.

Comment: Good point. That makes me rethink my logic. Because I don't really have a way to check the ldap syntax by ldap untill I actually write it to ldap. So I should either do custom checks, or rewrite is_valid() into something like si_valid_and_successfully_saved().

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you just have an additional step of validation.
You could, depending on which are your specific needs:

- Put a [validator](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/validators/) on your fields, to check for simple things, or
- Implement additional cleaning on your [field](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) or on [multiple fields at once](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other),

but in every case if the form is not valid for any reason (as in your case), is_valid should return False.

Comment: I agree. See my comment on petraszd answer.